# One to many relationship in Product Ordering System with Crow's Foot Notation

Tags: database, relational-database, data-modeling, erd

In the image below you can see a **one-to-many** relationship between **Order** and **Order_Product**.

I am fine with this except two things:

- I think the circle should be removed because any single order in **Order** is associated with ***one or many*** rows in **Order_Product** table.
- The single bar should be double bar because any single row in **Order_Product** is associated with **one and only one** order in the Order table.

Can anyone correct me if I am wrong?

[image: one to many relationship between Order and Order_Product tables]

The complete ERD could found here:
https://circle.visual-paradigm.com/simple-order-system/

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL--text. If you want to discuss reflecting the DDL in symbols, then add an image to DDL.

Comment: There is no question in this post. PS Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. About how you are 1st stuck, following what published design method, from what competent presentation/reference/textbook? [ask] [Help [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: Fine now?  @philipxy

Comment: I have no idea why you would think it would be.

Comment: @philipxy there seems a very clear question here. (In the version I see now) o.p. has raised a couple of points they see as issues, suggested emendations, and asked if their understanding is correct. There's even a question mark.

Comment: @AntC I have no idea why you think your comment is an argument against my comments. PS I suggest you try to clearly phrase what you think the question the post is trying to ask is. I'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many variants and shorthand forms of Crow's foot notation, so firstly check your references to see if they give a precise specification. I'll compare your diagram to [wikipedia's description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model#Crow%27s_foot_notation). But see also their 'Related diagramming convention techniques'.

> - I think the circle should be removed because any single order in Order is associated with one or many rows in Order_Product table.

*If* the circle is deliberate, it's showing it's valid within this model for there to be an `Order` with zero `Order-Product`. Typically at the start of a customer placing an order, there's not yet any Products mentioned. Or the `Order` might be for services rather than discrete `Product`: my car is making a funny noise, please send a mechanic.

> - The single bar should be double bar because any single row in Order_Product is associated with one and only one order in the Order table.

Yes in that wikip description and example diagram, there should be both a min and max. 'One and only one' would be a common specification with Foreign Key references. It would be an obvious shorthand to put a single bar in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781451/crows-feet-one-vs-one-and-only-one longer discussion(s) of one bar vs two bars.